# Pseudocode in the style of Algorithm Design (Kleinberg & Tardos)

Tags: pseudocode

How do you write pseudocode in the style below? I tried using the `verbatim` environment but I can't seem to get the variables italicized and symbols like `\in` to work. I also tried using the `algorithmic` and `algorithm2e` packages but they seem much more restrictive than the style used in this book.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the docs, e.g for [algorithm2e](https://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf)? You can set the style of every keyword, function,... individually.

Comment: I will keep looking in the docs. I guess I'm mainly posting just in case I'm overthinking something really simple. The psuedocode in the text basically reads like regular English so I was hoping there was some straightforward way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't need an extra algorithms package and the `tabbing` environment (standard LaTeX) suffices.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\tab{\hspace{1.5em}}
\begin{document}
{\ttfamily
\begin{tabbing}
  \tab\=\tab\=\tab\=\tab\=\tab\=\tab\=\kill
  Initially, all $m\in M$ and $w\in W$ are free\\
  While there is a man $m$ who is free and hasn't proposed to every woman\\
  \>Choose such a man $m$\\
  \>Let $w$ be the highest-ranked woman in $m$'s preference list\\
  \>\>to whom $m$ has not yet proposed\\
  \>If $w$ is free then\\
  \>\>$(m,w)$ become engaged\\
  \>Else $w$ is currently engaged to $m'$\\
  \>\>If $w$ prefers $m'$ to $m$ then\\
  \>\>\>$m$ remains free\\
  \>\>Else $w$ prefers $m$ to $m'$\\
  \>\>\>$(m,w)$ become engaged\\
  \>\>\>$m'$ becomes free\\
  \>\>Endif\\
  \>Endif\\
  Endwhile\\
  Return the set $S$ of engaged pairs
\end{tabbing}%
}
\end{document}
```